# How to remain only the last character in a list

Tags: r, list, character

I got a list like
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jF8ya.png)

How to only remain the last character among the characters of every element in the list, for example: the list[[642]] becomes [[642]] character[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jF8ya.png) '1995'.

Answer (score 0):

If your list `mylist` is all vectors of the same type with variable length then:

```
output <- sapply(mylist, function(x) x[length(x)])
```

Will return a vector of the last values of each vector.

Answer (score 0):

An option is `tail`

```
output <- lapply(mylist, tail, 1)
```